# Javascript not selecting the html element which was added later using innerHTML via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was creating a todo's list with JS. I have attached the code snippet for the same. I Have three hard coded todos in html and with each todo there are two buttons(**'x'** to remove the todo **'y'** to mark it as done) associated. Now for this hard coded todos everything is working fine. Now, to add a new todo I have this  tag where todo text is entered and after clicking enter I am embedding them to html using innerHTML, while embedding the dynamically added todos are visible in DOM. But The problem is that the buttons(**'x' and 'y'**) associated with the todo is not working as expected. Further I tried to debug my problem and I found out that the buttons('x' and 'y') that are not getting selected. I could not understand why is this happening. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
const todoInp = document.querySelector('.add input')
const todos = document.querySelector('.todos')


const remove = document.querySelectorAll('.remove')

const doneBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.check')

todoInp.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.value !== '') {
    const todoVal = e.target.value
    const todo = document.createElement('div')
    todo.classList.add('todo')

    todo.innerHTML = `
        <p>${todoVal}</p>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="remove">x</button>
          <button class="check">y</button>
        </div>
    `

    todos.appendChild(todo)

    todoInp.value = ''
  }
})






doneBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const mainPar = btn.parentElement.parentElement
    mainPar.classList.toggle('done')
  })
})

remove.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const parent = btn.parentElement
    const mainPar = parent.parentElement
    mainPar.remove()
  })
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.container{
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 50px;
}

.add,
.todos{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.add label{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darkblue;
}
.add input{
    background: white;
    padding: 13px;
    border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.add input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.add input::placeholder{
    color:#ccc
}

.todo{
    color: darkblue;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.todo:last-child{
    border: 0
}

.todo p{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.buttons button{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #aaa;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.buttons button:hover{
    color:black;
}
.todo.done p{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    color: orangered;
    text-decoration-style:double;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="add">
    <label>ADD TODO</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write your To do">
  </div>
  <div class="todos">
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 1</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 2</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 3</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good solution to these kinds of problems is the use of [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation). The reason your X and Y buttons are not working is because the `querySelectorAll` has already run before the new buttons exist, hence the `addEventListener` could not be added.

Comment: Ooh right @Reyno, so I will be able to solve my problem using Event Delegation right?

Comment: That's correct! If you can't figure out event delegation just comeback and update your question with your attempt(s) and we help you from there. Success!

Comment: yea sure will do, thank you so much @Reyno

Comment: Ugly but it works, unbind the buttons and bind them again each time you add a todo item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your X and Y buttons are not working is because the querySelectorAll has already run before the new buttons exist, hence the addEventListener could not be added.

Using [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) you only need a single click event on your parent element. Then inside the event handler you can check what element was pressed.

```js
const todoInp = document.querySelector('.add input');
const todos = document.querySelector('.todos');

todoInp.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.value !== '') {
    const todoVal = e.target.value;
    const todo = document.createElement('div');
    todo.classList.add('todo');
    
    todo.innerHTML = `
        <p>${todoVal}</p>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="remove">x</button>
          <button class="check">y</button>
        </div>
    `;
    todos.appendChild(todo);
    todoInp.value = '';
  }
})

// Add a single click event to the todos wrapper
todos.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // exit if we don't click on a button
  if(e.target.nodeName !== 'BUTTON') return;
  
  // get `mainPar` element
  const mainPar = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
  
  // remove todo item
  if(e.target.classList.contains('remove')) {
    return mainPar.remove();
  }
  
  // check todo item
  if(e.target.classList.contains('check')) {
    return mainPar.classList.toggle('done');
  }
}, false);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.container{
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 50px;
}

.add,
.todos{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.add label{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darkblue;
}
.add input{
    background: white;
    padding: 13px;
    border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.add input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.add input::placeholder{
    color:#ccc
}

.todo{
    color: darkblue;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.todo:last-child{
    border: 0
}

.todo p{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.buttons button{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #aaa;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.buttons button:hover{
    color:black;
}
.todo.done p{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    color: orangered;
    text-decoration-style:double;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="add">
    <label>ADD TODO</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write your To do">
  </div>
  <div class="todos">
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 1</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 2</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 3</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

While delegation is a perfectly fine solution, I tend to take an (in my opionion) simpler approach, and simply bind the handlers to the new elements:

```js
const todoInp = document.querySelector('.add input')
const todos = document.querySelector('.todos')


const remove = document.querySelectorAll('.remove')

const doneBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.check')

todoInp.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.value !== '') {
    const todoVal = e.target.value
    const todo = document.createElement('div')
    todo.classList.add('todo')

    todo.innerHTML = `
        <p>${todoVal}</p>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="remove">x</button>
          <button class="check">y</button>
        </div>
    `

    todos.appendChild(todo)
    bindRemove(todo.querySelector('.remove'));
    bindDone(todo.querySelector('.check'));
    todoInp.value = ''
  }
})

const bindDone = (btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const mainPar = btn.parentElement.parentElement
    mainPar.classList.toggle('done')
  })
}

const bindRemove = (btn) => {
 btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const parent = btn.parentElement
    const mainPar = parent.parentElement
    mainPar.remove()
  })
}

doneBtns.forEach(bindDone)

remove.forEach(bindRemove)
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.container{
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 50px;
}

.add,
.todos{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.add label{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darkblue;
}
.add input{
    background: white;
    padding: 13px;
    border: 0.5px solid #ccc;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.add input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.add input::placeholder{
    color:#ccc
}

.todo{
    color: darkblue;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.todo:last-child{
    border: 0
}

.todo p{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.buttons button{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #aaa;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.buttons button:hover{
    color:black;
}
.todo.done p{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
    color: orangered;
    text-decoration-style:double;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="add">
    <label>ADD TODO</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Write your To do">
  </div>
  <div class="todos">
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 1</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 2</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <p>Todo 3</p>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
        <button class="check">y</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @dave highly appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the buttons list, after delete or add todo. This is hard to do and I suggest you use it this way:
You must edit HTML buttons to look like this:

```
 <button class="remove" onclick="remove(this)">x</button>
 <button class="check" onclick="done(this)">y</button>
```

After did that change your javascript file to:

```
const todoInp = document.querySelector('.add input')
const todos = document.querySelector('.todos')


todoInp.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {

if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.value !== '') {
  const todoVal = e.target.value
  const todo = document.createElement('div')
  todo.classList.add('todo')

  todo.innerHTML = `
    <p>${todoVal}</p>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="remove" onclick="remove(this)">x</button>
      <button class="check" onclick="done(this)">y</button>
    </div>
  `

todos.appendChild(todo)

todoInp.value = ''
    
}
})



function done(btn){
    const mainPar = btn.parentElement.parentElement
    mainPar.classList.toggle('done')
}

function remove(btn){
    const parent = btn.parentElement
    const mainPar = parent.parentElement
    mainPar.remove()
}
```

Comment: Thank you @HoM highly appreciate your help!!